# MIT-OCW 18.650 - prove convergence in probability

Tags: probability, statistics

> This is a question from MIT-OCW 18.650 (Fall 2016), [Problem Set 1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-650-statistics-for-applications-fall-2016/resources/mit18_650f16_pset1/)

For $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, let $X_n$ be a random variable such that $\mathbb{P}\left[X_n=\frac{1}{n}\right]=1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $\mathbb{P}[X_n = n]=\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Does $X_n$ converge in probability?

**My Solution**:
Convergence in probability, i.e. $X_n\xrightarrow{\quad\text{p}\quad} X$, is proved by showing that

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|\gt\epsilon) = 0,\qquad\forall\epsilon\gt 0 \qquad\text{eq.1}
$$

Now, the random-variable $X$ can be obtained by computing the above two probabilities under the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$, i.e.

$$
\mathbb{P}(X=0) = 1 \qquad\text{eq.2}
$$

Now, substituting eq.2 into eq.1, we get

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|\gt\epsilon) & = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-0|\gt\epsilon) \\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n|\gt\epsilon) \qquad\text{since, }X_n\gt 0\\
& = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n\gt\epsilon) \qquad\text{eq.3}
\end{align*}
$$

How to show that eq.3 evaluates to zero-probability?

Comment: Try using Markov's inequality

Comment: Yeah, this is it!

Comment: Since it converges in mean, it must converge in probability. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_mean).

Comment: Yeah, but the question asked to explicitly prove the convergence in probability and not show it as a consequence of convergence in Lp.